# SVM parameter optimization in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I want to optimize SVM parameters in Opencv. But, every time I use `train_auto` I get `C=1` and `gamma=1`. Some people use LibSVM but I could not write a wrapper for that. Both `trainingData` and `labels` are taken from an existing code which gives good results so I am trying to get the same parameters for that code with `train_auto`. In the original code `C=312.5` and `gamma=0.50625`. I saw that somebody used `CvStatModel` for python, is it necessary for C++? Where do I make a mistake?
Thanks in advance.

The Code:

```
CvParamGrid CvParamGrid_C(pow(2.0,-5), pow(2.0,15), pow(2.0,2));
CvParamGrid CvParamGrid_gamma(pow(2.0,-15), pow(2.0,3), pow(2.0,2));
if (!CvParamGrid_C.check() || !CvParamGrid_gamma.check())
    cout<<"The grid is NOT VALID."<<endl;
CvSVMParams paramz;
paramz.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
paramz.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
paramz.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.000001);
svm.train_auto(trainingData, labels, Mat(), Mat(), paramz,10, CvParamGrid_C, CvParamGrid_gamma, CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::P), CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::NU), CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::COEF), CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::DEGREE), true);
svm.get_params();
cout<<"gamma:"<<paramz.gamma<<endl;
cout<<"C:"<<paramz.C<<endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

I modified the code as follows `paramz = svm.get_params()` and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried the initial parameters?  How was the result? How long it took tor training? Thanks.